# ~てしまう form with ある？

Tags: grammar, translation, word-choice

This might be a stupid question, but here goes.

I was just wondering how to say something like, "*it was (placed) there, unfortunately*," in Japanese without using 残念ながら。

And I thought, **「そこであってしまった」**。

So, is using **てしまう** with **ある** correct? If not, what are the other ways to say it without using 残念ながら？

Comment: I feel そこであってしまった is correct, though you can use そこにあってしまった depending on the situation. If you add some situations, I may tell when you can use them and have to use other sayings.

Comment: @Chance I know that てしまう is perfectly fine with normal verbs. I'm just curious as to whether it's okay or not to use the てしまう form with existence verbs like ある/いる.
For example, is 「十円だけあってしまう」 correct for "unfortunately, I only have 10 yen."?

Comment: As for 十円だけあってしまう  is wrong; it feels like you hate to have any money but you can't help having 10 yens. You should say 十円しかない instead.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a good example because what you regret is not 10 yen existing or being in some place but you having **only** 10 yen. Is that what you really wanted to ask?

Comment: @aguijonazo I know might've given a bad example sentence, but all I'm confused about is whether it is grammatically correct (and natural-sounding) to use the teshimau with aru.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the very least, you *must* say そこ**に** when you use ある or いる. I'm sure you learned this rule along with the verbs ある and いる themselves. If you say そこ**で** by mistake, no one expects the verb ある will follow.

そこ**に**あってしまった is a correct sentence, at least grammatically speaking. In a stilted literary work, it can mean something like "Alas, [it] was unfortunately there!", but we seldom say this in reality. 10円だけあってしまう would mean something strange like "(I want to be penniless but) I end up having 10 yen".

Answer (score 2):

As is hinted in your question, you'd be better saying そこに置かれてしまった

If you said そこであってしまった in conversation it would be 99.99% of the time understood as そこで会って（遭って/逢って）しまった

Comment: Aah, I can certainly see your point. But still, is it grammatically correct though (using teshimau with aru, I mean)?